# NPM nodemon and debug no output in terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, output

I have this simple code:

```
const express = require('express');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const debug = require('debug');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use('/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css')));
app.use('/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js')));
app.use('/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/jquery/dist')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/views/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    debug(`listening on port ${chalk.green(port)}`);
});
```

The problem is that whatever I do, the output for starting the app `listening on port 4000` does not appear, but the rest is ok, everything works as it should. It should 100% work and maybe you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the documentation and your app here is a trimmed down example of your app, modified, and the output.

documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug

Your app (trimmed down and modified slightly) - **note the addition of the `something`. This is what debug attaches to**

```
const express = require('express');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const debug = require('debug')('something');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3004;

debug('some debug statement');

app.listen(port, () => {
    debug(`listening on port ${chalk.green(port)}`);
});
```

The call from a terminal line:

```
$ DEBUG=something node ~/path_to_your_project/project_name/app.js
```

The output:

Chriss-MBP-3:untitled1 lcsharp$ DEBUG=something node

```
~/WebstormProjects/untitled1/app.js
  something some debug statement +0ms
  something listening on port 3004 +9ms
```

Comment: the question is about the `debug` module not about `console.debug`

Comment: Thanks. Revising my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `debug` module then you have to initialize the logger with a namespace:

```
const debug = require('debug')('my-namespace')
```

By default the output of `debug` is not logged at all, you need to use the `DEBUG` environment variable to define what should be logged. How depends on the shell you use, and could look like this:

```
DEBUG=* node index.js
```

`DEBUG=*` means that everything is logged, as `*` is a wildcard.

If you would like to only log `my-namespace` it has to be:

```
DEBUG=my-namespace node index.js
```

You can divide your loggin into individal parts like:

```
const debugApp = require('debug')('my-namespace:app')
const debugModuleA = require('debug')('my-namespace:module-a')
const debugModuleB = require('debug')('my-namespace:module-b')
```

And with `my-namespace:*` you can log `app`, `module-a` and `module-b`

The same can be done for `nodemon`:

```
DEBUG=my-namespace nodemon index.js
```